# Use a single-line command to find the cardinality of all the values within a column within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how would I use a single-line command to find the cardinality of all the values within a column within a dataframe? Using only pandas. I have a column of data made up of different strings and I
want to count the number of occurrences of each value within that column. Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal':['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'dog', 'bird', 'bird']})
```

How would get the cardinality of each string?

cat : 1
bird : 3
dog: 2

so that I could also us it to make a bar plot using pandas

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
results = df['Animal'].value_counts()
```

If you want to call the value of a specific animal, just:

```
results['dog']
2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in Python collection for this, the [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
print(Counter(['cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'dog', 'bird', 'bird']))
# Counter({'bird': 3, 'dog': 2, 'cat': 1})
```